# How do I cause pseudo classes to reflow?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-class

I have this carousel that has children with animations. Everytime I change the slide, I want the animations to restart/reflow. The problem is that the animations are applied on a :before pseudo class. I searched for causing an element to reflow and I came up with something like:

```html
const reset_animation = (el) => {
    el.style.animation = "none";
    el.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */
    el.style.animation = null;
 }

document.querySelectorAll(`.${carouselItem[i]}`).forEach((el) => {
    reset_animation(el)
})
```

but it does not affect the pseudo classes. I also tried getting the pseudo class with window.getComputedStyle but I can't set the properties since all of it is read only.

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting JS to update the style of a pseudo element is to have that style set using a CSS variable.

For example:

```css
.withafter {
  --name: expand; /* the name of the animation for the after pseudo element */
  width: 20vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
}
.withafter::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  animation: var(--name) 10s linear;
}
@keyframes expand {
  to {
   transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="withafter"></div>
```

Then when you want to set it to none set the CSS property on the actual element using `el.style.setProperty('--name', 'none')` instead of setting the el's animation-name.